# SQL UDF to get the most recent record basis parameter date in a transactional dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

My Data

| RowID | UserId | REC_START_DATE | REC_END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 | 2015-01-05T00:00:00Z | 2015-01-05T00:00:59Z |
| 2 | 31 | 2015-01-05T00:01:00Z | 2015-01-05T00:01:59Z |
| 3 | 31 | 2015-01-05T00:02:00Z | 2015-01-05T00:02:59Z |
| 4 | 31 | 2015-01-05T00:03:00Z | 2015-07-21T23:59:59Z |
| 5 | 31 | 2015-07-22T00:00:00Z | 2015-07-22T00:00:59Z |
| 6 | 31 | 2015-07-22T00:01:00Z | 2015-07-22T23:59:59Z |
| 7 | 31 | 2015-07-23T00:00:00Z | 2015-07-23T00:00:59Z |
| 8 | 31 | 2015-07-23T00:01:00Z | 2016-05-22T23:59:59Z |
| 9 | 31 | 2016-05-23T00:00:00Z | 2016-05-23T00:00:59Z |
| 10 | 31 | 2016-05-23T00:01:00Z | 2016-05-23T00:01:59Z |
| 11 | 31 | 2016-05-23T00:02:00Z | 2016-05-23T00:02:59Z |
| 12 | 31 | 2016-05-23T00:03:00Z | 2017-04-26T23:59:59Z |
| 13 | 31 | 2017-04-27T00:00:00Z | 2017-04-27T00:00:59Z |
| 14 | 31 | 2017-04-27T00:01:00Z | 2017-04-27T23:59:59Z |
| 15 | 31 | 2017-04-28T00:00:00Z | 2017-04-28T00:00:59Z |
| 16 | 31 | 2017-04-28T00:01:00Z | 2017-07-02T23:59:59Z |
| 17 | 31 | 2017-07-03T00:00:00Z | 2017-07-03T00:00:59Z |
| 18 | 31 | 2017-07-03T00:01:00Z | 2017-07-03T00:01:59Z |
| 19 | 31 | 2017-07-03T00:02:00Z | 2017-07-03T00:02:59Z |
| 20 | 31 | 2017-07-03T00:03:00Z | 2018-01-03T11:23:20Z |
| 21 | 31 | 2018-01-03T11:23:21Z | 2018-03-29T23:59:59Z |
| 22 | 31 | 2018-03-30T00:00:00Z | 2018-03-30T00:00:59Z |
| 23 | 31 | 2018-03-30T00:01:00Z | 2018-03-30T23:59:59Z |
| 24 | 31 | 2018-03-31T00:00:00Z | 2018-03-31T00:00:59Z |
| 25 | 31 | 2018-03-31T00:01:00Z | 2018-04-08T23:59:59Z |
| 26 | 31 | 2018-04-09T00:00:00Z | 2018-04-09T00:00:59Z |
| 27 | 31 | 2018-04-09T00:01:00Z | 2018-04-09T00:01:59Z |
| 28 | 31 | 2018-04-09T00:02:00Z | 2018-04-09T00:02:59Z |
| 29 | 31 | 2018-04-09T00:03:00Z | 2018-05-27T23:59:59Z |
| 30 | 31 | 2018-05-28T00:00:00Z | 2018-05-31T23:59:59Z |
| 31 | 31 | 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z | 2018-06-01T23:59:59Z |
| 32 | 31 | 2018-06-02T00:00:00Z | 2018-06-02T00:00:59Z |
| 33 | 31 | 2018-06-02T00:01:00Z | 2018-09-26T23:59:59Z |
| 34 | 31 | 2018-09-27T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-27T00:00:59Z |
| 35 | 31 | 2018-09-27T00:01:00Z | 2018-09-27T23:59:59Z |
| 36 | 31 | 2018-09-28T00:00:00Z | 2018-09-28T00:00:59Z |
| 37 | 31 | 2018-09-28T00:01:00Z | 2018-09-28T00:01:59Z |
| 38 | 31 | 2018-09-28T00:02:00Z | 2018-09-28T00:02:59Z |
| 39 | 31 | 2018-09-28T00:03:00Z | 2018-09-28T00:03:59Z |
| 40 | 31 | 2018-09-28T00:04:00Z | 2018-09-28T00:04:59Z |

With this transactional data, I want to create a user defined function accepting a date as parameter. Basis that date, I want to return the eligible row applicable during that time period.

For e.g., if I pass a paramDate as '2015-08-01', I should be getting rowId 8 as result since for this period, row 8 had the most recent data (till 2016-05-22). Similarly, for a single end date, if I have multiple entries, I would want the most recent timestamp for that date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getLastRec (
    @paramDate date
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    SELECT top 1 * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE REC_END_DATE > @paramDate AND year(REC_END_DATE) = year(@paramDate)
ORDER BY REC_END_DATE DESC
```

```
SELECT * FROM getLastRec('2015-08-01')
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating the function slightly seems to be working for me

```
CREATE FUNCTION getLastRec (
    @paramDate date
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    SELECT top 1 * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE REC_END_DATE >= @paramDate AND REC_START_DATE <= @paramDate
ORDER BY REC_END_DATE DESC
```

```
select * from getLastRec('2015-08-01') -- date not in data - row 8
select * from getLastRec('2017-05-01') -- date not in data - row 16
select * from getLastRec('2017-07-02') -- date in data - row 16
select * from getLastRec('2017-07-03') -- date in data with multiple entries - row 20
select * from getLastRec('2023-07-04') -- current date - last row
select * from getLastRec('2050-07-04') -- future date - last row
```